# SQL Server (via Pentaho): Delete takes way too long, just two rows per second

Tags: sql-server, pentaho, kettle

I am using the Delete-Step of Pentaho in order to delete about 200k rows (with 35 columns each) on an MSSQL Server Express table. 
Primary key is the condition
 I do sort the rows upon! 
Commit size is at 10k. 
Performance of the Server should not be the issue because I am able to insert with a speed of over 1000 rows per second.
Tried the same steps with a table that does not have a primary key constraint. Same issue.
Would appreciate any help!

Comment: With information given, how do you think we can help???

Comment: How long does it take to delete those rows directly, via tSQL?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Pentaho, but long deletes can often be attributed to foreign key relationships. Is your `PK` also a `FK` and is there a covering index on the `FK` table?

Comment: Primary Key is the ID from SalesForce. But that should not be the issue neither because first I do read all the rows from salesforce. <br>Other than that, the PK is not used anywhere else in SQL Server.<br>
Could try to execute the statement on the SQL Server. <br>However, how should the statement look like if I don't want to type in all the 400k PK-numbers into the WHERE-clause?

Answer (score 0):

> how should the statement look like if I don't want to type in all the 400k PK-numbers into the WHERE-clause?

Not sure what strategy Pentaho is using to run the deletes, but you might try loading the 400k IDs into a staging table or temporary table, and referencing that in the DELETE.  eg

```
delete from maintable where id in (select id from maintable_ids_to_delete)
```